# Oring Diodes: is RC discharge circuit needed for prevent disconnection issue?

Tags: power-supply, diodes, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

I have a new design implemented with oring diodes circuit as shown in picture below, where I have POE_VIN_24V coming from POE+ Module, and PHNX_DC_IN coming from phoenix connector, that is connected to RIGOL power supply.

[image]

I'm experiencing a problem where sometimes when I connect the PHNX_DC_IN, where the Rigol power supply is adjusted to 20V/4A, and while POE input is disconnected, and I see 0 Watts on power consumption, which looks like there is an electrical disconnection between the input and the rest of the design.

This happens at cases where I insert the phoenix power connector very frequently, in and out several times in a row, and fast enough. once this happens, I keep the connector inside, and turn/off the the rigol power supply, to ensure there is no mechanical issue with the connector. It seems like there is certain amount of time needed to pass in order to pass power again.

This behavior makes me suspect the C13-C17 capacitors after the oring diodes. where it could be that the delay I'm witnessing, is the time needed for these capacitors to discharge or something related to that. but I don't know how the disconnection could happen. since the cathode of the diodes in this case will be always higher than the anode, even after disconnecting/connecting power from the phoenix connector.

Note 1: +VIN_ALW is connected to +5V_ALW DC-DC and +3.3V_LDO:

[image]
Note 2: as it appears in the picture, I added 10K resistor (green) to ensure that the +5V_ALW EN and PG have a path to ground to discharge C12, once the +VIN_ALW is disconnected from the phoenix connector. (that actually helped a bit, but I'm not sure that was the root cause of the problem).

The question in mind is whether I need to put 10K resistor in parallel to C13-C17 to insure the discharging can be done more fast? and if this really could help, what is the explanation?

Note 3: +VIN_ALW is also connected only to 12V DC-DC:

[image]

Comment: If you have a scope or even am meter, monitor the voltage.  88uf is a lot of capacitance and discharging it through 20K will take seconds.  Your series inductor will ensure that the power supply overshoots so you may just be overcharging the caps, then showing zero current until they discharge.

Comment: What series inductor? I have parallel ferrites. How how can and inductor make a PSU overshoot?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using parallel ferrites, but the ferrites are inductors.  Even if they are not there I think your issue is that most commercial power supplies do not regulate downwards.  That is, if they sense that the voltage is too low, they increase the duty cycle which will increase the voltage.  But if they sense that the voltage is too high, they reduce the duty cycle, but the voltage will not drop immediately; it relies on the load current to pull it down.  When the diode is back-biased, there is no load current, so no power from the supply.